# Owl carousel extra space while displaying the actual image size

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, owl-carousel

I am using the reality wordpress theme, I am trying to display the actual image which is center focused in theme

Look [this](http://reality.inwavethemes.com/property/great-house-in-chicago/) I have modified the css to

```
.iwp-property-gallery-slider-v1 .owl-item figure img {    
        position: relative;
    width: auto;    
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

Here images are coming with extra white space at each end of the items. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: autowidth isn't something you control with the css. You need to enable it in the js with  autoWidth:true. https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html

Comment: @dantheman93 Thanks dear, You are awesome. Can you make this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autowidth isn't something that you can control with the css.

You need to enable it in the js with `autoWidth:true`

Check Documentation [Here](http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html)